# Excel VBA Runtime error 13 when accessing FullSeriesCollection via a name stored in a variable

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

When I'm trying to get or set various properties for charts using the FullSeriesCollection method, I'm running into an odd little problem. I can access them via index or the series name, but when I try to use a name stored in a variable, I get a run-time error 13 (Type mismatch). For example:

```
Dim trendname As String     'I've also tried Variant, but it still gives me error 13
    trendname = "Average"   'when the name is used directly as below

Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula               'This works 
Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection("Average").Formula           'This works 
Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection.Item("Average").Formula      'This works 
Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection(trendname).Formula           'This gives runtime error 13
Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection.Item(trendname).Formula      'This gives runtime error 13
Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection("" & trendname).Formula      '...but this works fine!
Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection.Item("" & trendname).Formula 'This works too
```

Is there a way I can get it to work referencing trendname alone, rather than needing to concatenate the variable with an empty string? Is there a different variable type I should be declaring trendname as, instead of Variant or String?
While the concatenation method does work, it looks rather silly, and I'm curious as to why it works when just using the variable by itself doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may already know, the Index argument must be a Variant.  So, even if you declare your variable as a Variant, once a string has been assigned to it, it's recognized as a string.  So you'll have to coerce the index to a Variant using the type conversion function CVar...

```
Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection(CVar(trendname)).Formula

or

Debug.Print Charts(1).FullSeriesCollection.Item(CVar(trendname)).Formula
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I didn't know variants get limited like that. This'll help me out with some other things that have been bugging me, too.